# How can I emphasize an impex macro if it is part of a string?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I emphasize an impex macro if it is part of a string?

We can do something like this:

```
$prefix=alpha
$contentCatalog=$prefixContentCatalog
```

... and $contentCatalog will return "alphaContentCatalog".

Can I make the macro more explicit with something like:

```
$contentCatalog={$prefix}ContentCatalog
```

... so that I can immediately see that the macro is `$prefix`? Is there a syntax for this? (NOTE: The curly brace is just an example. This syntax/symbol doesn't exist for this purpose)

Another example: If I have something like below, it becomes confusing:

```
$prefix=electronics
$contentCatalog=$prefixContentCatalog
$contentCatalogFolderName=$contentCatalogFolder
```

But it can be easier to understand if it can be written as:

```
$prefix=electronics
$contentCatalog={$prefix}ContentCatalog
$contentCatalogFolderName={$contentCatalog}Folder
```

Comment: I could not understand the requirement. In `$contentCatalog=$prefixContentCatalog`, the macro `$prefix` is clearly visible. Why do you want to put `{...}` around it? I may be missing something.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes, the first code block is OK. What I was asking / wondering if there is a way to make the macro easier to see / understand. I added another example to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hhmmm, unfortunately I don't think there is anything for this. I only see some workarounds like special naming for macro variables:

```
$_prefix_=electronics
$_contentCatalog_=$_prefix_ContentCatalog
$contentCatalogFolderName=$_contentCatalog_Folder
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is an alternate way to customize the micro via injecting property in local.properties and using ConfigPropertyImportProcessor.

```
 UPDATE GenericItem[processor = de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.ConfigPropertyImportProcessor]; pk[unique = true]
$contentCatalog = $config-ly.br.content.catalog
$contentCV = catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default = $contentCatalog]), CatalogVersion.version[default = Staged])[default = $contentCatalog:Staged]
```

and entries should be added in local.properties.

```
ly.br.content.catalog=TestContentCatalog
```

Note:This is useful when we have multi-country.